# Set maximum number of server redirects followed when using HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, http, url

Is there a way to mandate the maximum number of redirects that are followed when using HttpURLConnection?

```
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) uri.getURI().toURL();
        conn.connect();
```

I can only see an option to enable/disable redirects

```
conn.setFollowRedirects(true)
```

I want to set a max follow of 3 (it seems the default is 20), to prevent exceptions like this:

```
java.net.ProtocolException: Server redirected too many  times (20)
```

that are caused by circular redirects on some servers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the [http.maxRedirects](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html) property:

`System.setProperty("http.maxRedirects", "3");`

Comment: Thanks, it works. Although the property is only read once on startup so it needs to be set as a runtime property using "-Dhttp.maxRedirects=3"

Comment: @Joel actually it's enough to set this parameter before http calls, for example in some initialization method

Comment: @VitaliiFedorenko How do you know that?

Answer (score 2):

Accroding to [HTTP RFC](http://www.freesoft.org/CIE/RFC/1945/46.htm)

> A user agent should never
>   automatically redirect a request more
>   than 5 times, since such redirections
>   usually indicate an infinite loop.

[This forum post explains](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=267915) how to work around this

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just catch the exception? Changing the threshold number won't change the fact that the function has to report failure to you when it exceeds that number. In fact, lowering the threshold will increase the chances that the function will have to report failure in complex-but-legitimate redirect situations when it would have ultimately succeeded with a higher threshold.

Comment: I already do. The reason I want to limit the number of redirects has more to do with efficiency. Why follow a redirect 20 times? It's a waste of time if i'm crawling 1000s of sites at once and don't need this. Plus, seems strange not to have the option.