# java.net.ProtocolException: Server redirected too many times

Tags: java, rest, jersey

Getting error

> javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.net.ProtocolException: Server
>   redirected too many times (5)

while executing

```
javax.ws.rs.core.Response response = client.target("https://someurl")
            .request().get(javax.ws.rs.core.Response.class);
```

It seems that the exception was received after 5 redirection attempts.

Is there some way to configure the number of redirects allowed in Jersey client?

Comment: See related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775277/set-maximum-number-of-server-redirects-followed-when-using-httpurlconnection/4775434#4775434

Answer (score 0):

API protocol exception to indicate when the response is not according to specification

Comment: This is more of a comment